# Sharepoint 2013 Asset Library Search isn't working

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm new to sharepoint so I'm hoping that this is a simple user error:

I'm working in SharePoint 2013, and have added the Asset Library App.  I have uploaded about 15 images into the Asset Library app page.  They all show up fantastic.  I have tagged keywords in them with Adobe Bridge before importing them to Sharepoint.  The tags carried over into SP perfectly and are all showing up correctly in the document information under the field for Keywords.

When I try to search for my documents using the Sharepoint search bar, nothing shows up.  I have tried search for a single keyword, multiple keywords, document title, document type, a single letter, everything!  And yet there are never any results found.

I then found an option to turn on Enterprise Keywords.  I did that, and copied my Keywords field over to "Enterprise Keywords" Still no success.  No results found for anything at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question is off-topic here. Most likely you haven't configured search properly and/or no crawl was performed on the new data yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ondrej was correct, No crawl had been performed on the new data yet.

Like I said, I'm very new to SharePoint, and didn't know that it was set up to crawl only once a week.

It's been crawled now and the search feature works great!

Answer (score 0):

To search for property saved under Keywords, type `keywords:` before your tag word, i.e. if you're searching for all items containing keyword `Cat`, type in the search box:

```
keywords:Cat
```